# Scroll to the center of a table Horizontally using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table with more than 9 rows and each row is having columns double than the previous row and i want to scroll to the center of the table on page load.

What I have tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var outerContent = $('table');
    var innerContent = $('tbody');

    outerContent.scrollLeft((innerContent.width() - outerContent.width()) / 2);        
});
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: I'm not so sure that's true. Assuming your first row starts with 1 column, if each row doubles in columns, by row 20 you would have 1,048,576 columns. You would crash the browser long before reaching 512 rows. https://jsfiddle.net/304kL1pm/2/

Comment: @wrxsti oh they were actually 9. 512 were columns. it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the table inside of a div with the `overflow:scroll;` style. Then use `scrollLeft` on the div rather than the table.

```
let div = $('div');
div.scrollLeft($('table').width() / 2);
```

[Here is an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/304kL1pm/7/)